# Fit y=ax in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I wanna fit this as y=ax. However, the code doesn't work. Can anyone could help me?

```
def func():
    return a * x

F1 = [0.55, 0.45, 0.50, 0.65, 0.75, 0.80]
r1 = [18.2, 18.4, 18.8, 19.5, 20.0, 20.2]

plt.plot(F1, r1)
popt = curve_fit(func, r1, F)  # I supose it only returns one value
plt.plot(r1, popt * r1, 'g--')
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters.
```

Comment: There are so many errors in this code that it's difficult to even begin answering this. 
What is F1, what is r1??
Which of those is a, and which should be x? 
Exactly what are the data points that you want to curve fit?

Comment: Curve fit doesnt return one value. Have you checkt what popt looks like ? You should use F1 and not F

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Run the code to see what the results of curve_fit are like and follow the logic carefully.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as curve_fit

def f(x,a):
    return a*x

F1 = [ 0.55, 0.45, 0.50, 0.65, 0.75, 0.80 ]
r1 = [ 18.2, 18.4, 18.8, 19.5, 20.0, 20.2 ]

result = curve_fit(f, r1, F1)
print (result)

print ( 'F1 = %s * r1' % result[0][0] )

plt.plot(r1, F1, 'b.')

p = [ result[0][0] * _ for _ in r1  ]
plt.plot(r1, p, 'g--')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you have no inputs to your fitting function. `func` doens't know what `a` and `x` are, so can't return `a*x`.

Also, `curve_fit` doesn't just return popt, but also `pcov`, so you have to catch that in the returned values

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# func needs x and a as inputs
def func(x, a):
   return a*x

F1=[0.55,0.45,0.50,0.65,0.75,0.80]
r1=[18.2,18.4,18.8,19.5,20.0,20.2]

plt.plot(r1,F1, 'bo')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, r1, F1)
plt.plot(r1,popt*r1,'g--')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: the reason the fit is not great is because your line must go through the origin. You can get a better fit using `a*x+b`, but that's not what you asked how to do.